# my post request get response as https but does not return to a new page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm send a post request and I get the response like this

" [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
url: 'https://login.somenewloginpage'}"

and what I want to do is I want to open a new page via that url but it does not direct to the new page.

```
const login= () => async () => {

  const api = `somePostRequest`

  fetch(api, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-url-encoded',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res  //maybe I should do something in this part...
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use `fetch()` with `async/await` syntax :

```
const login= () => async () => {

  const api = `somePostRequest`;

  const response = await fetch(api, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-url-encoded',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const data = await response.json(); // { url: 'https://login.somenewloginpage'}

  window.location.replace(data.url); // <-- Redirection
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but it keep shows me this error...invalid json response body at https:login.somewhere page

Comment: This is a different problem. The API is not returning what you think it does. Check your network tab and inspect the response. Handle the error with a try/catch block.

Comment: Ha nice :) You're welcome, glad I could help. BTW I made a mistake in my code, it's actually `await response.json()`, yes it's asynchronous and returns a Promise, so it needs `await`. Not sure how this code could work with you without `await` though